# Could not find the Run option in IntelliJ for Spring Boot Applicaton

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I could not find any way to run the Spring Boot Maven application in IntelliJ. Maven clean, maven install and Build Project is working fine. But Run option is not showing and could not add the Main class in configuration.

[image: Edit Configuration]

Comment: The main class must follow some conventions to be runnable. It looks like it has compile errors? It's red in IntelliJ. Check it please. If you have doubts paste the class as formatted code.

Comment: @Mar-Z no errors in the main class, this is just a starter application. But still could not find what is the error.

Comment: If you have doubts please paste the MainApplication class as formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Maven/IDEA doesn't pick up your Project's structure, so it doesn't know where the source code is.

Try clicking "Reload All Maven Projects" in Maven Tool Window.

If that won't help you can:

- Close the project window `File | Close Project` and the IDE.
- Open a project in OS file explorer and remove all `*.iml` files and the `.idea` folder from a project.
- [Re-import the project from Existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#import-project)